# List of all standard .net 4.5 libraries (dlls)

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-4.5, .net-assembly

Where I can find a full list of all standard .NET assemblies (.dll files)?

Note: There is a [list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff462634(v=vs.100).aspx) for .net 4.0 client profile only, but I need a list for .NET 4.5 (full profile)

Comment: I think this may be helpful for other people who forgot to look into `Reference Assemblies` folder like me.

Comment: Could you SO user suggest how make this question less broad?

Comment: I agree with you. This isn't broad. It's a straight forward question. If I open a project that references a specific assembly I need to know if I should include that assembly when building and coping my executable to a location for users to run from. Was that assembly part of .Net or was it part of a NuGet package or was it manually added? Seems like a valid question to me to have a list of what's included in .Net by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate over to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5` and you'll see the entire list.

There's an online list of assemblies in the .NET Framework Client profile for v4:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff462634(v=vs.100).aspx

But there doesn't appear to be one for the newer ones.  So, I would just go off of what you see in that directory I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this would be to write your own reflection code to look at all of the assemblies in the .NET framework and pull out all of the unique assemblies.

Some pseudo code:

```
for each assembly in netAssemblies

    foreach type in assembly.GetTypes()

       if namespace hasn't been added

           add namespace
```

Comment: You could look at all of the .dlls in the directory that B.K. referenced.