# How to determine which "System" dlls need to be distributed with my .Net 4.8 Project

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a project targeting .Net 4.8 that uses the following DLLs ...

- Microsoft.Win32.Registry  <--- Found in Assemblies.Extensions
- System.Security.Principal.Windows <--- Found in Assemblies.Extensions
- System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController <--- Found in Assemblies.Framework

These references do not display in the Project's References listing however are copied to the respective /bin folders when building the project/solution.

Are these dll's distributed within .Net 4.8 et al or do I need to distribute them in my release package? If so, why? **If not, using C# how can I determine programmatically if a particular dll is contained within the .Net 4.8 distribution** so that I can remove it from my distribution package?

**Edit 1:**
What is not obvious to me is why were these dll's copied to the /bin folder in the first place. If they are distributed as part of .Net 4.8 then this seems superfluous and misleading.

**Edit 2:**
Given that these dll's may already exist on the end-users machine for reasons other than they are included in the .Net 4.8 distribution, merely not including them in my package may quickly lead to disastrous consequences if they are not already on another prospective end users machine.

Comment: "do I need to distribute them in my release package?" Nope, that's the point of using the .NET-framework. Just make your the framework is installed on the target-system.

Comment: "how can I determine programmatically if a particular dll is contained within the .Net targeted distribution so that I can remove it from my distribution package?" - I don't want to sound facetious, but you could simply see if the required functionality works after you run it *without* the file there

Comment: They are not framework assemblies, won't be available on the user's machine.  A basic way to get them is through a .NETStandard library, perhaps retrieved with Nuget.  They are glue, very small with [TypeForwardedTo] attributes that redirect a type to the specific framework assembly that implements the type.  Odds you need them are high.

Answer (score 0):

This  [answer regarding the dll's included with .Net distributions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046353/list-of-all-standard-net-4-5-libraries-dlls) answers the determining of what dll's are distributed and [this answer helps explain where these dll's originated](http://Does%20the%20Registry%20class%20in%20the%20Microsoft.Win32.Registry%20package%20get%20type-forwarded%20to%20the%20mscorlib.dll%20when%20used%20in%20the%20.NET%20Framework?).

With regard to why these dll's exist, I look forward to an explanation as it strikes me they serve no worthwhile purpose!

Hans Passant's comment above also explains the scenario well and would have been marked as the answer had he chosen to answer.